# Error code 0xd0000272 activating upgraded Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-activation

Recently I installed a Pro version of Windows 7 and activated it successfully. Then I ran Windows Media Creation Tool and upgraded the activated Windows 7 directly to Windows 10. The version of the Windows 10 is 1511.

Now I see that the Windows 10 fails to activate with error code 0xd0000272 claiming that Microsoft activation server is down.

I tried changing the product key option and entered the previous Windows 7 Product key, and I got the same error even after installing most current updates.

Is there any way to activate the Windows?

---

Edit: I tried calling the activation phone service, it asked for installation ID and I entered but at the end it refused to give the confirmation ID. Instead it gave some general information about usability of Windows 7 product key for Windows 10 after upgrading.

Comment: 0xd0000272 Is related to services and communication problems.

Comment: maybe you installed the Home Edition of Win10? Get the Pro ISO from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have upgraded directly from Windows 7! So the correct version is installed.

Comment: install Win10 Pro again with a clean ISO and use here the Win7 key

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes that worked.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to reinstall Windows using a clean [ISO that you can download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench). With the Version 1511 Microsoft now allows to enter a Windows 7/8 product key during setup. Do this and it should work.